# Keras: compute cosine distance between two flattened outputs

Tags: keras

EDIT2: my code https://github.com/hcl14/my_simple_LSTM

I have the model of the following structure: Two LSTMs (question and answer) and additional attention layer which can be considered on top of answer. Here is the version which uses sum and softmax to compare two outputs:

[image: LSTM]

```
#question
qenc = Sequential()
qenc.add(Embedding(output_dim=WORD2VEC_EMBED_SIZE, input_dim=vocab_size,
                   input_length=seq_maxlen,
                   weights=[embedding_weights]))
qenc.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(QA_EMBED_SIZE, return_sequences=True), 
                       merge_mode="sum"))
qenc.add(Dropout(0.3))
qenc.add(Convolution1D(QA_EMBED_SIZE // 2, 5, border_mode="valid"))
qenc.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_length=2, border_mode="valid"))
qenc.add(Dropout(0.3))

# answer
aenc = Sequential()
aenc.add(Embedding(output_dim=WORD2VEC_EMBED_SIZE, input_dim=vocab_size,
                   input_length=seq_maxlen,
                   weights=[embedding_weights]))
aenc.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(QA_EMBED_SIZE, return_sequences=True),
                       merge_mode="sum"))
aenc.add(Dropout(0.3))
aenc.add(Convolution1D(QA_EMBED_SIZE // 2, 5, border_mode="valid"))
aenc.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_length=2, border_mode="valid"))
aenc.add(Dropout(0.3))

# attention model
attn = Sequential()
attn.add(Merge([qenc, aenc], mode="dot", dot_axes=[1, 1]))
attn.add(Flatten())
#attn.add(Dense((seq_maxlen * QA_EMBED_SIZE)))
#attn.add(Reshape((seq_maxlen, QA_EMBED_SIZE)))
attn.add(Dense((qenc.output_shape[1]*(QA_EMBED_SIZE // 2))))
attn.add(Reshape((qenc.output_shape[1], QA_EMBED_SIZE // 2)))

# Plain sum - not working properly!
model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([qenc, attn], mode="sum"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation="softmax"))
```

The network here is working, but the plain sum + softmax is a wrong choice and does not give results desired. What I want is to use cosine similarity between `qenc` and `attn`, but their shapes are `(None, 48, 32)` (these numbers vary depending on data used). What I'm thinking about is to flatten both and use cosine similarity, comparing with 0-1 labels.

The problem is how to use cosine there? I can't flatten `qenc` as it is used in Merge when `attn` is calculated and shape matters there. I tried:

Lambda - doesn't work. I does not accept sequential model, just layers output, which is not layer, but tensor, so can't be added.

```
def cosine_distance(vests):
    x, y = vests
    x = K.batch_flatten(x)
    y = K.batch_flatten(y)
    x = K.l2_normalize(x, axis=-1)
    y = K.l2_normalize(y, axis=-1)
    return -K.mean(x * y, axis=-1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Lambda(cosine_distance)([qenc.layers[-1].output,attn.layers[-1].output]))
```

Intermediate flattening models - results in errors like "Merge object does not have batch_size attribute" or something like that:

```
flattened_attn = Sequential()    
flattened_attn.add(attn)    
flattened_attn.add(Flatten())

flattened_qenc = ...

model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([flattened_attn, flattned_qenc], mode="cos", dot_axes=1))
```

At last, I achieved to pass flattened data with shape `(None, 1536)`:

```
qenc = Sequential()
qenc.add(Embedding(output_dim=WORD2VEC_EMBED_SIZE, input_dim=vocab_size,
                   input_length=seq_maxlen,
                   weights=[embedding_weights]))
qenc.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(QA_EMBED_SIZE, return_sequences=True), 
                       merge_mode="sum"))
qenc.add(Dropout(0.3))
qenc.add(Convolution1D(QA_EMBED_SIZE // 2, 5, border_mode="valid"))
qenc.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_length=2, border_mode="valid"))
qenc.add(Dropout(0.3))
qenc.add(Flatten())

aenc = Sequential()
aenc.add(Embedding(output_dim=WORD2VEC_EMBED_SIZE, input_dim=vocab_size,
                   input_length=seq_maxlen,
                   weights=[embedding_weights]))
aenc.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(QA_EMBED_SIZE, return_sequences=True),
                       merge_mode="sum"))
aenc.add(Dropout(0.3))
aenc.add(Convolution1D(QA_EMBED_SIZE // 2, 5, border_mode="valid"))
aenc.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_length=2, border_mode="valid"))
aenc.add(Dropout(0.3))


unflattened_qenc = Sequential()
unflattened_qenc.add(qenc)
unflattened_qenc.add(Reshape((aenc.output_shape[1],aenc.output_shape[2])))

# attention model
attn = Sequential()
attn.add(Merge([unflattened_qenc, aenc], mode="dot", dot_axes=[1, 1]))
attn.add(Flatten())
#attn.add(Dense((seq_maxlen * QA_EMBED_SIZE)))
#attn.add(Reshape((seq_maxlen, QA_EMBED_SIZE)))
attn.add(Dense((aenc.output_shape[1]*(QA_EMBED_SIZE // 2))))
attn.add(Reshape((aenc.output_shape[1], QA_EMBED_SIZE // 2)))
attn.add(Flatten())


model = Sequential()
attn.add(Merge([qenc, attn], mode="cos", dot_axes=1))
```

And got the error:

```
  attn.add(Merge([qenc, attn], mode="cos", dot_axes=1))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qa-lstm-attn.py", line 175, in <module>
    attn.add(Merge([qenc, attn], mode="cos", dot_axes=1))
  File "/home/hcl/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 492, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/home/hcl/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 617, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hcl/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/legacy/layers.py", line 202, in call
    '(at least 2). Got: ' + str(inputs))
TypeError: Merge must be called on a list of tensors (at least 2). Got: Tensor("flatten_3/Reshape:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32)
>>> qenc.output_shape
(None, 1536)
>>> aenc.output_shape
(None, 48, 32)
>>> attn.output_shape
(None, 1536)
```

How to do cosine then?

Keras v. 2.1.4

UPD: After fixing `model.add()` copypaste error I have:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([qenc, attn], mode="cos", dot_axes=1))
```

Error message:

```
  File "qa-lstm-attn.py", line 195, in <module>
    callbacks=[checkpoint])
  File "/home/hcl/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 963, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/home/hcl/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1637, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/home/hcl/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1483, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/home/hcl/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 86, in _standardize_input_data
    str(len(data)) + ' arrays: ' + str(data)[:200] + '...')
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 3 array(s), but instead got the following list of 2 arrays: [array([[ 1676,    19,   328, ...,  1612,    29,  4220],
       [    0,     0,     0, ...,     4,    27,  4807],
       [ 2928,     9,  1652, ...,   125,     9,   181],
       ...,
       [ 5970,   14...
```

How the callback is called:

```
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_squared_error",
              metrics=["accuracy"])

print("Training...")
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=os.path.join(MODEL_DIR, "qa-lstm-attn-best.hdf5"),
    verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
model.fit([Xqtrain, Xatrain], Ytrain, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
          nb_epoch=NBR_EPOCHS, validation_split=0.1,
          callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

I think Keras does not understand that one of the models was reused and expects additional input.

My model is actually a modified version of this code, which does not work properly, because model just learns to answer False always (the author warns about it):

https://github.com/sujitpal/dl-models-for-qa

https://github.com/sujitpal/dl-models-for-qa/blob/master/src/qa-blstm-attn.py

---

## EDIT

Explanations for @daniel-möller:  I want to implement the model from the article https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04108 . As long, as the model computes cosine between question and answer, my labels are 0 and 1 (answer matches question and not). The dataset consists of a question and 4 variants of the answer, where one is correct. Here is how I prepare it (`kaggle.py`) by creating 4 data pairs, with one having True:

```
def get_question_answer_pairs(question_file, is_test=False):
    qapairs = []
    fqa = open(question_file, "r")
    
    data = json.load(fqa)
    for l, line in enumerate(data):
        
        if l%100==0:
            print(l)
        
        question = line["question"]+" "+line["support"]
        
        qwords = tokenizer(question)
        
        #qwords = nltk.word_tokenize(question)
        
        if len(qwords)>100:
            qwords=qwords[:100]
        
        if not is_test:
            correct_ans = line["correct_answer"],
            answers = [line["distractor1"],line["distractor2"],line["distractor3"],correct_ans[0]]
            
            new_order = [0,1,2,3]
            random.shuffle(new_order)
            
            answers = [ answers[i] for i in new_order]
            
            correct_ans_idx = new_order[-1]
            
            # training file parsing
            #correct_ans_idx = ord(correct_ans) - ord('A')
            for idx, answer in enumerate(answers):
                #awords = nltk.word_tokenize(answer)
                #print(answer)
                awords = tokenizer(answer)
                qapairs.append((qwords, awords, idx == correct_ans_idx))
        else:
            # test file parsing (no correct answer)
            answers = cols[2:]
            for answer in answers:
                awords = nltk.word_tokenize(answer)
                qapairs.append((qwords, awords, None))
    fqa.close()
    return qapairs
```

You don't need to recompute qapairs, they are already saved and loaded via line in the main program:

```
with open("processed_input.pickle", 'rb') as f:
    qapairs = pickle.load(f)
```

Here is the example (please scroll to the right to see answers and true-false labels):

```
>>> qapairs[0]
(['what', 'type', 'of', 'organism', 'is', 'commonly', 'used', 'in', 'preparation', 'of', 'foods', 'such', 'as', 'cheese', 'and', 'yogurt', '', 'mesophiles', 'grow', 'best', 'in', 'moderate', 'temperature', 'typically', 'between', '25°c', 'and', '40°c', '(77°f', 'and', '104°f)', 'mesophiles', 'are', 'often', 'found', 'living', 'in', 'or', 'on', 'the', 'bodies', 'of', 'humans', 'or', 'other', 'animals', 'the', 'optimal', 'growth', 'temperature', 'of', 'many', 'pathogenic', 'mesophiles', 'is', '37°c', '(98°f)', 'the', 'normal_human', 'body', 'temperature', 'mesophilic', 'organisms', 'have', 'important', 'uses', 'in', 'food', 'preparation', 'including', 'cheese', 'yogurt', 'beer', 'and', 'wine'], ['viruses'], False)
>>> qapairs[1]
(['what', 'type', 'of', 'organism', 'is', 'commonly', 'used', 'in', 'preparation', 'of', 'foods', 'such', 'as', 'cheese', 'and', 'yogurt', '', 'mesophiles', 'grow', 'best', 'in', 'moderate', 'temperature', 'typically', 'between', '25°c', 'and', '40°c', '(77°f', 'and', '104°f)', 'mesophiles', 'are', 'often', 'found', 'living', 'in', 'or', 'on', 'the', 'bodies', 'of', 'humans', 'or', 'other', 'animals', 'the', 'optimal', 'growth', 'temperature', 'of', 'many', 'pathogenic', 'mesophiles', 'is', '37°c', '(98°f)', 'the', 'normal_human', 'body', 'temperature', 'mesophilic', 'organisms', 'have', 'important', 'uses', 'in', 'food', 'preparation', 'including', 'cheese', 'yogurt', 'beer', 'and', 'wine'], ['mesophilic', 'organisms'], True)
>>> qapairs[2]
(['what', 'type', 'of', 'organism', 'is', 'commonly', 'used', 'in', 'preparation', 'of', 'foods', 'such', 'as', 'cheese', 'and', 'yogurt', '', 'mesophiles', 'grow', 'best', 'in', 'moderate', 'temperature', 'typically', 'between', '25°c', 'and', '40°c', '(77°f', 'and', '104°f)', 'mesophiles', 'are', 'often', 'found', 'living', 'in', 'or', 'on', 'the', 'bodies', 'of', 'humans', 'or', 'other', 'animals', 'the', 'optimal', 'growth', 'temperature', 'of', 'many', 'pathogenic', 'mesophiles', 'is', '37°c', '(98°f)', 'the', 'normal_human', 'body', 'temperature', 'mesophilic', 'organisms', 'have', 'important', 'uses', 'in', 'food', 'preparation', 'including', 'cheese', 'yogurt', 'beer', 'and', 'wine'], ['protozoa'], False)
>>> qapairs[3]
(['what', 'type', 'of', 'organism', 'is', 'commonly', 'used', 'in', 'preparation', 'of', 'foods', 'such', 'as', 'cheese', 'and', 'yogurt', '', 'mesophiles', 'grow', 'best', 'in', 'moderate', 'temperature', 'typically', 'between', '25°c', 'and', '40°c', '(77°f', 'and', '104°f)', 'mesophiles', 'are', 'often', 'found', 'living', 'in', 'or', 'on', 'the', 'bodies', 'of', 'humans', 'or', 'other', 'animals', 'the', 'optimal', 'growth', 'temperature', 'of', 'many', 'pathogenic', 'mesophiles', 'is', '37°c', '(98°f)', 'the', 'normal_human', 'body', 'temperature', 'mesophilic', 'organisms', 'have', 'important', 'uses', 'in', 'food', 'preparation', 'including', 'cheese', 'yogurt', 'beer', 'and', 'wine'], ['gymnosperms'], False)
```

The next step is done by the function `vectorize_qapairs()` in `kaggle.py`/ On github it uses cosine distance, I have changed it to cosine similarity (1 - most similar (zero angle), 0 - not similar(orthogonal)) according to your comment:

```
def vectorize_qapairs(qapairs, word2idx, seq_maxlen):
    Xq, Xa, Y = [], [], []
    for qapair in qapairs:
        Xq.append([word2idx[qword] for qword in qapair[0]])
        Xa.append([word2idx[aword] for aword in qapair[1]])
        #Y.append(np.array([1, 0]) if qapair[2] else np.array([0, 1]))
        # cosine similarity: 1 for 0 degree angle
        Y.append(np.array([1]) if qapair[2] else np.array([0]))
    return (pad_sequences(Xq, maxlen=seq_maxlen), 
            pad_sequences(Xa, maxlen=seq_maxlen),
            np.array(Y))
```

As you can see, it places 1 if there is "True" label and zero otherwise.

Now I want the model to compute cosine, just as on the picture, and then compare it with 0-1 label. I believe what you did is correct and model is working now, but I want it to start learning instead of outputting numbers around accuracy=0.75 which corresponds to outputting always False. I have even simplified the code now for debugging purposes, throwing out convolutions:

```
#question
qenc = Sequential()
qenc.add(Embedding(output_dim=WORD2VEC_EMBED_SIZE, input_dim=vocab_size,
                   input_length=seq_maxlen))
qenc.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(QA_EMBED_SIZE, return_sequences=True), 
                       merge_mode="sum"))

aenc = Sequential()
aenc.add(Embedding(output_dim=WORD2VEC_EMBED_SIZE, input_dim=vocab_size,
                   input_length=seq_maxlen))
aenc.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(QA_EMBED_SIZE, return_sequences=True),
                       merge_mode="sum"))

# attention model

#notice that I'm taking "tensors" qenc.output and aenc.output
#I'm not passing "models" to a layer, I'm passing tensors 
#that was the problem with your lambda

attOut = Dot(axes=1)([qenc.output, aenc.output]) 
    #shape = (samples,QA_EMBED_SIZE//2, QA_EMBED_SIZE//2)
    #I really don't understand this output shape.... 
    #I'd swear it should be (samples, 1, QA_EMBED_SIZE//2)
attOut = Flatten()(attOut) #shape is now only (samples,)
#attOut = Dense((qenc.output_shape[1]*(QA_EMBED_SIZE // 2)))(attOut)
#attOut = Reshape((qenc.output_shape[1], QA_EMBED_SIZE // 2))(attOut) 
attOut = Dense((qenc.output_shape[1]*(QA_EMBED_SIZE)))(attOut)
attOut = Reshape((qenc.output_shape[1], QA_EMBED_SIZE))(attOut) 



flatAttOut = Flatten()(attOut)
flatQencOut = Flatten()(qenc.output)
similarity = Dot(axes=1,normalize=True)([flatQencOut,flatAttOut])

model = Model([qenc.input,aenc.input],similarity)

# I tried MSE and binary crossentropy
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy",
              metrics=["accuracy"])

print("Training...")
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=os.path.join(MODEL_DIR, "qa-lstm-attn-best.hdf5"),
    verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
model.fit([Xqtrain, Xatrain], Ytrain, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
          nb_epoch=NBR_EPOCHS, validation_split=0.1,
          callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

The code is not entirely mine of course, I used the implementation from https://github.com/sujitpal/dl-models-for-qa  which computes `Dense(2)` layer and suffers from the same problem of learning to output only false.

I wonder if I am making some mistake I cannot understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with branches. Don't use sequential models with branches.

You can use `qenc` and `aenc` as `Sequential` models, no problem, because they're a single path, no ramifications.

I'm taking examples here from the first part of your code.

**Updating the calls that are using keras 1:**

```
#question
qenc = Sequential()
qenc.add(Embedding(output_dim=WORD2VEC_EMBED_SIZE, input_dim=vocab_size,
                   input_length=seq_maxlen))
qenc.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(QA_EMBED_SIZE, return_sequences=True), 
                       merge_mode="sum"))
qenc.add(Dropout(0.3))
qenc.add(Convolution1D(QA_EMBED_SIZE // 2, 5, padding="valid"))
qenc.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, padding="valid"))
qenc.add(Dropout(0.3))

# answer
aenc = Sequential()
aenc.add(Embedding(output_dim=WORD2VEC_EMBED_SIZE, input_dim=vocab_size,
                   input_length=seq_maxlen))
aenc.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(QA_EMBED_SIZE, return_sequences=True),
                       merge_mode="sum"))
aenc.add(Dropout(0.3))
aenc.add(Convolution1D(QA_EMBED_SIZE // 2, 5, padding="valid"))
aenc.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, padding="valid"))
aenc.add(Dropout(0.3))
```

Taking care to watch what the input and output shapes of each model are:

- qenc output shape is: `(samples, (seq_maxlen-4)/2, QA_EMBED_SIZE//2)`
- aenc output shape is: `(samples, (seq_maxlen-4)/2, QA_EMBED_SIZE//2)`

But `attn` is merging two branches, let it be a functional API `Model`

```
# attention model

#notice that I'm taking "tensors" qenc.output and aenc.output
#I'm not passing "models" to a layer, I'm passing tensors 
#that was the problem with your lambda

attOut = Dot(axes=1)([qenc.output, aenc.output]) 
    #shape = (samples,QA_EMBED_SIZE//2, QA_EMBED_SIZE//2)
    #I really don't understand this output shape.... 
    #I'd swear it should be (samples, 1, QA_EMBED_SIZE//2)
attOut = Flatten()(attOut) #shape is now only (samples,)
attOut = Dense((qenc.output_shape[1]*(QA_EMBED_SIZE // 2)))(attOut)
attOut = Reshape((qenc.output_shape[1], QA_EMBED_SIZE // 2))(attOut)
```

- Notice the output shape: `(samples, (seq_maxlen-4)/2, QA_EMBED_SIZE // 2)`.
- Notice also that this attention part **requires two inputs**

If you "need" to have the `attn` model separate from the others for some reason, please tell me, for the code above will need a little change

Now, you can flatten the outputs of `qenc` and `attn`, no problem, you just can't do it "inside" the `qenc` model.

```
flatAttOut = Flatten()(attOut)
flatQencOut = Flatten()(qenc.output)
similarity = Dot(axes=1,normalize=True)([flatQencOut,flatAttOut])
```

Finally create the full model:

```
model = Model([qenc.input,aenc.input],similarity)
```

> **Warning:** this model outputs the similarity - are you sure `y_train` is similarity? (Shape = (samples,1)).
> If it is, ok. If it's not, please detail your question better and explain the output of your model, your training data, and when and where you want this similiarity to appear.

---

### Loss function to balance clases:

You can try a custom loss function to balance the classes, since you have a 75%-25% ratio for false-true outputs.

```
import keras.backend as K

def balanceLoss(yTrue,yPred):

    loss = K.binary_crossentropy(yTrue,yPred)
    scaledTrue = (2*yTrue) + 1 
        #true values are 3 times worth the false values
        #contains 3 for true and 1 for false

    return scaledTrue * loss

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=balanceLoss)
```

Not sure if binary_crossentropy goes well with this type of balance, but you may also try mean squared error.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your detailed answer! I tried to explain my logic as much as possible in the edit to my post. Now everything works, but the model seems to quickly reach 75% accuracy which means outputting always false, the same problem that initial realization suffered from. I wonder if it is possible to make it work properly, Thanks nevertheless!

Comment: If it quickly reaches that, you can keep training for a (very) long time and see if later it will get better. It's common for the model to initially find the easiest way as predicting everything equal to the most present output.

Comment: Reducing the learning rate may help in that process, although "adam" normally finds its way after a long time.

Comment: You may also consider adding some activation function to the Conv and Dense layers, such as `tanh` or `sigmoid`, this makes the model train more smoothly.

Comment: I had once a model that I had to train for very very long, and the loss seemed frozen (changes were smaller than the amount of digits the screen showed). The model was apparently predicting zeros for everything and I couldn't find the problem. So one day I just left it training for really long and suddenly it found a path.

Comment: And I suggested a custom loss to lower the difference between true and false results.

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestions! I tried everything and trained for 50 epochs with plain SGD with no momentum, but still no success. I can make it overfit (higher val loss, lower train loss) using big batch size(500), but that's all at the moment. I will keep trying though

Comment: From an overfitting model, use 'adam' again, it's easier if you got to that point. Pure SGD may need too many manual adjustments. (You can also adjust the initial `lr` with `Adam(lr=....)`)

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are using the `Sequential` model and the following code block causes the problem (note you use `attn.add()` instead of `model.add()`).

```
model = Sequential()
attn.add(Merge([qenc, attn], mode="cos", dot_axes=1))
```

I think it makes more sense for you to use the `Graph` model in your case.

Also, you made a mistake here

```
# Plain sum - not working properly!
model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([qenc, attn], mode="sum"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation="softmax")) # <--- ERROR
```

Softmax on a single neuron makes no sense! You should use `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')` instead. Alternatively, you can use `Dense(2, activation='softmax')`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Please excuse me for mistakes, I was just trying a lot of things, got errors everywhere, and wrote this code to summarize my efforts. Unfortunately, after fixing `model.add()`, I still get the error, where I suppose Keras does not understand that I am reusing already used model. I will update my question to show what happens